# jQuery Validate Plugin - Group Checkbox addMethod Not Firing

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am trying to make sure that one checkbox is chosen, however it seems that the validation plugin's `group` option is not being picked up, along with the custom `addMethod`. I've read over the docs and through multiple stack overflow posts - while finding similar issues, I don't see any that are failing the way this one is - in other words I'm stumped. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a codepen for example: http://codepen.io/jaegs/pen/KVVYYw

*Note: There's a rule for the `emailField` commented out, uncommenting this and clicking the `submit` button shows that the validation plugin is working.*

**JS**

```
$.validator.addMethod('groupCheck', function(value) {         
    return $('.msGroup:checked').size() > 0; 
}, 'Please choose at least one subscription.'); 

var checkboxes = $('.msGroup'); 
var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e, i){ 
    return $(e).attr("name"); 
}).join(" "); 

$('#formInput').validate({ 
    debug: true,
    //rules: {
    //  emailField: "required"
    //}, 
    groups: { 
        checks: checkbox_names
    }, 
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){ 
      if (element.attr("name") == "emailField"){ 
        error.appendTo('#emailError'); 
      } else { 
        error.appendTo('#checkboxError'); 
      } 
    } 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formInput"> 
  <label>E-mail Address*</label>
  <input type="text" name="emailField" id="emailField"/> 

  <div id="emailError"></div> 

  <h4>Select the e-mails you would like to receive</h4> 
  <ul> 
    <li> 
      <input class="msGroup" type="checkbox" name="one" id="one" /> 
      <label for="one">one</label> 
    </li> 
    <li> 
      <input class="msGroup" type="checkbox" name="two" id="two" /> 
      <label for="two">two</label> 
    </li> 
    <li> 
      <input class="msGroup" type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" /> 
      <label for="three">three</label> 
    </li> 
  </ul> 

  <button type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton">SUBSCRIBE</button> 

  <div id="checkboxError"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Checkboxes are very common `<form>` elements and you would never need to write a custom method/rule to simply make them "required" for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Title**:  Group Checkbox addMethod Not Firing
>
> "Maybe I can't blend the `addMethod` with the `groups` and `errorPlacement` options?"

There is no such restriction.

The reason your custom method is *"not firing"* is because you have not assigned your new custom rule to any of the fields.  In other words, [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) merely *creates* the custom method/rule; you'll still need to assign the custom rule so the plugin knows which fields to use it on.

Example...

```
// create a custom rule
$.validator.addMethod('customRule', function(value, element, params) {         
    ....
}, 'Error Message.'); 

// initialize the plugin
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {  
        myField: {
            customRule: true  // assign the custom rule
        }
    },
    ....
```

---

---

FYI - The `groups` option simply consolidates the messages from several elements.  It is not a rule.

Also, checkboxes are very common `<form>` elements and you would never need to write a custom method/rule to simply make them "required" for validation.

You have two options:

1. Give all three checkbox elements the same `name` and, as per HTML, they will all be considered as a single "data input" within a `<form>` container.  The jQuery Validate plugin will automatically make at least one checkbox required when the `required` rule is used and you will not need the `groups` option.

**DEMO 1:  http://jsfiddle.net/5qjk9bg6/**

```
$('#formInput').validate({
    rules: {
        one: { // <- all three checkboxes have this name
            required: true
        }
    },
    ....
```

---

2. If, for whatever reason, you need all three checkboxes to each have a different `name`, then use the `require_from_group` method included within [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js).  Using this method, you'll get a validation message next to each checkbox.  To eliminate this message duplication, you would use the `groups` option.

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/ckchxxyd/**

```
$('#formInput').validate({
    rules: {
        one: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.msGroup']
        },
        two: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.msGroup']
        },
        three: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.msGroup']
        }
    },
    groups: { // combine the three error messages into one
        myGroup: "one two three"
    },
    .....
```

In a situation where you have a lot of checkboxes and using the `rules` option would be cumbersome, rules can instead be declared using the `.rules()` method as follows...

**DEMO 2B:  http://jsfiddle.net/ckchxxyd/1/**

```
$('.msGroup').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [1, this]
    })
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the clear write up @Sparky! Are you familiar with using `addMethod` to tie in functionality to the validation? ...The reason I'd like to use a custom `addMethod` is because my form actually contains about 20 checkboxes with different `names`, grouped together by `class`. And when the user submits the form without checking any off, they'd get a single error message at `#checkboxError` - Maybe I cant blend the `addMethod` with the `groups` and `errorPlacement` options? ...I'll most likely use your second solution if all else fails.

Comment: thanks for the help @Sparky - I've checked your submission as the answer